# Unable to get posts related to a child category

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, posts

I want to get al the posts, assigned to a child category. I am using the below code to get the posts but this code is working for some categories and not with all. I am sharing the piece of code.

I am passing these arguments and category names to get the posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 0,
    'category_name' => $category_name
    );
$Products_Query = new WP_Query($args);
```

some old categories are already there and I create some new categories and assign them posts to all categories. But now this code is not working with all categories.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the return value of `get_cat_ID($category_name)` is 0, the category name you provided doesn't exist. Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but maybe you intended to use `get_the_category()` or `get_the_terms()` on the current $post and query other posts for what this returns?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is not enough information here to be able to help. For example you have a problem with `get_cat_ID` but you don't show us the code where you are using it. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all of the relevant information so we are able to help.